# When I load the image in the folder "drawable" - have different image sizes

Tags: android, drawable

faced with such a situation. When I load the image in the folder "drawable" - have different image sizes. Image before download have **the same size in pixels**, and different size in bytes

Explained to what is wrong and how to fight it?

[image]

```
if (menu_item.get_Item_Use() == true ) {

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_arrow_icon);
        } else {    

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_arrow_icon_pressed);


        }
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Max,I have quick question : Both types(Black & White Arrow) images placed in same drawable folder OR one in drawable and other in drawable-mdpi/hdpi ?

Comment: I understand the matter themselves folders

Comment: picture is the same for all folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at your screenshot : there is something weird...

> drawable-hdpi -> ic_menu_arrow_icon_pressed.png

and

> drawable-xhdpi -> ic_menu_arrow_icon.png

The icons of these drawable looks like shortcut ??

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it there and then copied to other folders

Comment: well, personnally, that may not be the best solution, but I have only 1 drawable folder (except when working for tablet). Put there your best drawables (not too big, optimize them) and that's all. (apk is lower)

Answer (score 0):

Understood, android takes first pictures from the folder where you download them, and then those that you copied